# Filling Blank Rows from Cells Above Conditionally

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I originally used some script where the blank rows in the first 3 columns of data in my worksheet were filled from the previous row.  The script is:

```
    Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SearchRange = Columns("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In SearchRange

          If cell.row > 1 Then cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

        Next cell
    End If
```

Although that is fine for blank rows in between those columns I have a problem where the blanks are alongside text in column D I do not wish to fill. I tried something like:

```
   If Not Like "*FUEL*" Or Like "ACCOUNTS*"
```

yet I have trouble with the syntax in using this in a conditional statement. My pasted snip will make sense...I hope.  I want to fill just the row beside the word Jacqui in Column D but not Fuel or Accounts. NB. The word Jacqui is not constant.

[Excel Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKVB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cell.row to reference column D.

```
Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set SearchRange = Columns("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In SearchRange
        If cell.Row > 1 And Not (Cells(cell.Row, "D") Like "ACCOUNTS*" Or Cells(cell.Row, "D") Like "FUEL*") Then _
            cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    Next cell
End If
```